# How to find MT2002 Offending DLL?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-pipelines

In trying to build my Xamarin.iOS project using VSTS, I keep getting this error:

> MTOUCH: error MT2002: Failed to resolve
>   "System.Configuration.ConfigurationException" reference from "System,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

I understand it means that some DLL is referencing something improperly. However, when I debug through the simulator it works fine. When I load a similar project, it works fine (and builds through VSTS). is there an easy way to identify/find the offending file/reference so I can try and fix it?

Comment: Lots and lots of google hits for this problem, much better documented too.  This question is pretty unlikely to produce a better canonical Q+A.

Comment: I see lots of hits saying that there is a bad reference DLL. I see none that say how to FIND the bad reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From within an IDE you can use the assembly browser to see which .dll) inside your solution) has reference for `System, Version=4.0.0.0` has this is not the version shipped by XI (nor a PCL). Note that there might be more than one assembly that has a reference to this assembly (and type).

From the command-line you can use `grep` (at least on macOS, I don't recall the Windows specific tool) to find which .dll contains the string `ConfigurationException`.

**Side Notes:**

- the reason why it works in the simulator is that the JIT is used (so anything missing will throw at runtime, not a build time) and, by default, the managed linker is disabled (and it needs to be able to resolve symbols to rewrite any code).
- a different solution might work *if* there's not dependency that reach the missing symbol. In such case the linker will just eliminate the code (instead of resolving it). However if `ConfigurationException` is reachable (by static analysis) then it needs to be present for the linker to re-write the assemblies. IOW the linker can accept *bad* assemblies (or references) as long as final application code does not require it.

Comment: Thanks! For me it was System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. I believe I changed PCL focus and that caused the issue. Removing references to it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to keep the dependency, I changed the Linker Behavior in iOS Build properties and I could run the app on my device after wasting a few hours. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem appear after migration to NETStandart 2.0 from PCL. I should add System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension nuget package to platform projects and problem gone.